# VBA code to not allow user to select a cell with certain text

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet to copy a users data from the previous day, then delete any numerical values but keep cells with "NA".  What I want is for users to not be able to change/delete the cells that still have "NA" in them.  I found some code that used OFFSET to move down one cell if a certain cell was selected (based on the row and column) but I haven't been able to figure out how to use the OFFSET to move down one cell if the current cell contains "NA".  (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3820-excel-lock-cell-without-protecting-sheet.html)  This worksheet is already locked with a Quality-set password, so I can't do anything to unlock the spreadsheet, then select the "NA" cells to be locked, then relock the spreadsheet, thus looking for a creative way to keep the cells from being selected or changed.  Also, the code would need to run all the time, not just when a macro was selected to run.  Any ideas?

Comment: Create a worksheet change event and check with `.Find` if the targetrange contains `" NA"`. If so > Do something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible for the user to open the book without macros enabled, then I'm not sure what you're asking is possible.

If you can assume macros are enabled though, you could use events to either prevent the user selecting the cell (similar to the OFFSET you mention) or you could track changes manually onto a hidden tab in order to note changes and deal with them as you see fit. There are many ways you can achieve the latter, just search "VBA tracking changes to a sheet" etc.

This is how you'd use the OFFSET method:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells(1, 1).Text = "NA" Then
        Beep
        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind though, this is a very simplistic method. It won't prevent users selecting multiple cells (a range) and deleting the contents. Nor will it prevent values being pasted to range that includes the 'NA'.

**UPDATE:**
The following is an improved version that will at least prevent users from selecting multiple cells (for pasting into or deleting) if one of the cells contains "NA".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim testarea As Range
    Set testarea = Intersect(UsedRange, Target.Cells)
    If Not (testarea Is Nothing) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell_to_check In Intersect(UsedRange, Target.Cells)
            If cell_to_check.Text = "NA" Then
                Beep
                Cells(cell_to_check.Row, cell_to_check.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
                Do Until Selection.Text <> "NA"
                    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
                Loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This is still slightly flawed however, as it is still possible to drag-fill cells from other areas over a cell containing "NA".

Comment: What if user selects a range of cells

Comment: Hence my final paragraph, @JvdV . I'm just working on an alternative that can handle that.

Comment: Cool! I was just thinking, maybe  something on the lines of locking cells that contain NA using findnext when opening workbook? Maybe that's useful

Comment: Improvement offered @JvdV ... and yes, I know it still isn't perfect.  ;-)

Comment: I thought OP mentioned that locking cells (and the required protection) is excluded from potential solutions..?